# Why does my webstart applet crash?

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl, java-web-start, jnlp

So I switched from trying to use the appletloader for Lwjgl,
I am trying to use webstart now.
I think I've nearly got it but I get the weirdest error ever, I cant solve it.

So I hope any of you might be able to.
Ask me anything regarding my problem.

Here's the error I was talking about.

[image: The error]

```
<!-- JNLP File run.jnlp --> 

<jnlp 
  spec="1.0+" 
  codebase="file:///C:/Users/Rose/Desktop/AppletTest" 
  href="sudApplet.jar"> 
  <information> 
    <title>test</title> 
    <vendor>test</vendor> 
    <homepage href=""/> 
    <description>test</description> 
    <description kind="short">test</description> 
    <icon kind="splash" href="logo.png" />
    <offline-allowed/> 
  </information>
  <resources> 
    <j2se version="1.4+"/> 
    <jar href="sudApplet.jar" main="true"/>
    <extension name="lwjgl" href="file:///C:/Users/Rose/Desktop/AppletTest/extension.jnlp" />
  </resources> 
  <applet-desc 
         name="SudokuApplet"
         main-class="sud.main.MainClass"
         width="347"
         height="355">
     </applet-desc>
</jnlp>
```

And the extension

```
<jnlp codebase="file:///C:/Users/Rose/Desktop/AppletTest" href="extension.jnlp"> 
  <information> 
    <title>LWJGL</title> 
    <vendor>lwjgl.org</vendor> 
    <homepage href="http://lwjgl.org/"/> 
    <description>LWJGL webstart extension</description> 
    <description kind="short">LWJGL webstart extension</description> 
    <offline-allowed/> 
  </information>
  <update check="background" policy="always"/> 
  <security> 
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources> 
    <jar href="lwjgl.jar"/>
    <jar href="lwjgl_util.jar"/>
    jar href="slick.jar"/>
    <jar href="jinput.jar"/>
    jar href="jdom.jar"/>
  </resources> 
  <resources os="Windows">
    <j2se version="1.4+"/> 
    <nativelib href="native_windows.jar"/>
  </resources> 
  <resources os="Linux">
    <j2se version="1.4+"/> 
    <nativelib href="native_linux.jar"/>
  </resources>   
  <resources os="Mac OS X">
    <j2se version="1.4+"/> 
    <nativelib href="native_macosx.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="SunOS" arch="x86">
    <j2se version="1.4+"/> 
    <nativelib href="native_solaris.jar"/>
  </resources>  
  <component-desc />
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Two things: First, the two letters."PK", generally mean you're looking at a zip or jar file. Check that extension.jnlp is really a jnlp and not a misnamed jar. Second, check your tags. There are several unclosed jar tags in the second block you posted.

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller I closed those tags now for as far as I know, But I still get the same error.
Also That extension JNLP isn't a jar, Because its just a txt file saved as jnlp.